# What does "take it easy and riff? mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang

I came across the phrase in the 7th episode of the 4th season of *Rick and Morty*. Here is the context:

> Morty: You know, Rick, I'm sure you want to jump into another crazy adventure, but can we just relax and and maybr watch some interdimensional cable?
>
> Rick: I'm cook if you are.
>
> Morty: Honestly, that sounds great. We don't need to try so hard, you know. Let's just **take it easy and riff**, you know.

Comment: I'd guess it means the same thing as "to play it by ear" i.e. improvise. Word of advice, though: don't use this expression in conversation because nobody will know what you're talking about. Rick and Morty uses wordplay a lot.

Comment: You could also ask about "I'm cook if you are" which is more wordplay or made up slang (unless it is a typo for "I'm cool..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Take it easy and riff" and expression created by the writers.  A riff is a repeated musical phrase. To "riff" on something means to take a theme and repeat it, often with small variations. It can also mean "to improvise around a theme".

So figuratively it means "to make it up as we go along". Morty is suggesting that they don't make any plans, but just have fun and do whatever feels right.

As with other scripted shows, Rick and Morty don't speak "naturally" they are funnier and wittier than people would be if they don't have team of scriptwriters planning what they are going to say.

Comment: It's not a "made-up expression" - it's slang for improvising/making something up [on the fly](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+fly). It probably evolved from the musical "riff", but is now applied to pretty much anything. [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=riff) even has "I riffed up an excuse..." as an example.

Comment: I mean "take it easy and riff".  I don't think that is a standard expression

Comment: Why do you think "take it easy and riff" is an expression and not just part of a sentence? To me, it's similar to *Let's take it easy and have a pizza delivered* -- it's just words strung together to communicate meaning, not an expression someone invented.